# Module import errors with Virtual Environments and VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I have created a virtual environment to install some Python modules. I am using `mini-conda` to manage and activate the environments.

One issue that I am facing is that the code runs fine when I run it through the terminal with the virtual environment activated.

However, the same code does not run when I use the "Run Code" button (Ctrl + Alt + N) in VSCode. It gives me Module Not Found Error.

How can I run the code from VSCode in the context of my virtual environment?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the same interpreter in VSCode;
To do this you should use `Python: Select Interpreter` option;
`CTRL+Shift+p`(default key-bindings) and search for `Python: Select Interpreter`  or search for it in the VSCode settings.

Comment: Thanks laurbtzt. :) I was able to find the settings and then select the activated virtual environment. However, I still kept getting the same module error. Maybe I am not selecting it properly.

Comment: I clicked on the virtual environment from the list that appears when looking for a Python Interpreter and the list pop-up then disappears. After that, I click on the Run Code button and get the same error.

Comment: When you "Run Code" you'll see in the terminal what VSCode tried to run;
Can you paste here the output?
I am thinking that may be a problem with you `PYTHONPATH`

Answer (score 1):

You must have the [**Code Runner**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension installed because the `Run Code` option is provided by the **Code Runner** extension.

The triangle button for running code in the upper right corner has three options, among which `Run Code` is the way to run code provided by the **Code Runner** extension, while `Run Python File` and `Debug Python File` are the way to run and debug code provided by Microsoft's official extension **[Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)**.

[image]

Running the code with the `Run Code` option will run the code with the **Code Runner** extension. And **Code Runner** does not change the interpreter as you select a different interpreter in the ***Select Interpreter*** panel. It seems to always use the preferred interpreter from the system environment variables.

So although you are in a virtual environment and have some packages installed. But when you run code with `Run Code`, the interpreter is not the virtual environment of your choice. Although you have selected the virtual environment interpreter in the selection panel, this is only valid for `Run Python File` and `Debug Python File` provided by the **Python** extension.

So, run the code with the `Run Python File` option provided by the **Python** extension. Or install the packages you need for the interpreter environment currently used by **Code Runner**.

*You can check the currently used interpreter with the following code*

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```